# Should I include my age in my resume?

Tags: interviewing, resume, argentina

We all know that the age can be calculated, only if you include your birthday, which I think anyone should do.

I am from Argentina and some people just decide to include it and others don't

But I wonder if maybe including both the birthday and the age could be nice.. I think it gives the impression that at least it is updated and also makes you keep it updated too.

Also I think you make it a bit easier to the other person so that he doesn't have to calculate it.

Maybe it does not make a positive effect, but would it make a negative effect to include it?

So, should I include it both the age and the birthday? Only the birthday? Only the age? Maybe none of them?

Comment: Perhaps this is off-topic, but there's no need to include your age or birthday on your resume. During the application process and background check they obtain this information casually.

Comment: Which country are you in? That makes a material difference to the answer.

Comment: Like @Jake said, this really depends on country. In the USA? Nearly no reason to put it on your resume. But in Germany, when I was proofreading CVs nearly all of them had their birthday on them - if you look up German CV examples nearly all have a place for this. I'd recommend [edit]ing your question to include your country because of the impact country has on things like this.

Comment: @Jake  I am from Argentina, does it make a difference?

Comment: @CMosychuk why do you think this may be off-topic? I really don't think so

Comment: Why does this question deserve 2 downvotes? It shows reasonable effort, it is useful and clear. Don't go downvoting questions just because you don't agree with the content, which in this case, is based on your limited worldview restricted to a single country.

Comment: @MaskedMan Because in the USA it's very unusual so they downvote on reflex. In Europe it's normal.

Comment: @TheMathemagician The OP is from Argentina, not US. Even if he were from US, that is no justification for downvoting. Voting is not meant to indicate one's agreement with the question. People are free to vote based on any whim but I just wanted to point out that they should use votes more responsibly (or else this is another Quora in the making). Also if people don't know about the work practices in another country, they should just refrain from voting. What do engineers do when someone asks them for medical advice, for example?

Comment: @MaskedMan You misunderstood my comment. I'm agreeing with you and criticizing the downvoters.

Comment: @TheMathemagician Sorry about that, my comment wasn't directed to you specifically (even though I mentioned you there), it was meant to be a response to the reason you mentioned. You are correct in your explanation of why this happens, my response was to state why this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Are there age limitations on when you can start and when you have to stop working?

Comment: @JeffO no, there arent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is generally no reason to include a birthday on a resume.  So there is no need to include an age.

It is extremely rare that an employer would care about how old you are unless you are applying for, say, a part in a TV show set in a high school.  Many countries have age discrimination laws that make employers want to avoid that information-- if a resume is rejected and that resume doesn't indicate that the applicant was part of a protected class, the employer can't be sued for discrimination.  Sure, it's often possible to guess based on school graduation dates but there is no reason to either make that guessing easier or to confirm the guess (maybe you graduated much earlier or later than normal).

If you're applying to one of the small handful of jobs where age is a legitimate qualification, just include a birth date.  There is no reason to include an age-- your resume is going to be saved off in many places in many different systems that you'll have no access to.  You don't want information on it to go bad.

Comment: It might be good to include country in this as it depends a lot on where the job you are applying for is based.

Comment: -1 This is a very US centric answer.

Answer (score 5):

**You should follow the standard that is most common in your country.**  People reading resumes like it best when they find things done in a way they are used to. It makes it easier for the, to scan the resumes quickly.

If most resumes have the Date of Birth, there is no positive to be gained by also putting your age and it is easy for that to get out of date because you weren't thinking about that birthday you had 5 months ago when you send out a resume for a job you saw today.

I would assume very few people reading the resumes actually bother to calculate the exact age anyway, why would they it is irrelevant to the job and they are likely busy people. They might note that you are in your 20s or 40s and likely no more than that.

I would spend more time on things in your resume that are likely to be the key to getting the job. I would never drop a person from consideration because he was 23 instead of 24. I would drop one because he doesn't have the skill set I am looking for. Or if I can't tell if he does based on a poor presentation.

Comment: Great answer, but then how I can know which is the standard here in Argentina? I mean I know what my friends do or even close people, but how can I know what other people do? I don't have theirs resume.. :/

Comment: @PabloMatiasGomez Check for some examples on google. When I was writing my first resume, I found lots of them on google.